# Storyboard segue call sequence

Tags: xcode4, uistoryboardsegue

I have a button which calls a method on the same view. That button generates a data and takes me to another MapViewControlelr .I have 'prepareForSegue' method on the first view. But that prepareForSegue is called first right after button click. As a result my variables aren't getting updated from the method call. Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use GCD to load your data asynchronously and then perform the segue, something as follows:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", NULL);  
dispatch_release(queue);

dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
    // Generate data

    // Main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        // perform segue
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
    });
});
```

Also, instead of configuring the segue from button to newViewController - configure it **from mainViewController to newViewController** and then use `performSegueWithIdentifier` method